# accumulation of tmp files in fs.s3.buffer.dir

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, hive

I am running EC2 cluster with s3 (s3:// file system) . Here when I run any hive query or some hadoop command that operates on very big data, it copies tmp files on the local disk on the nodes before/after copying them to/from s3.  I know it can be configured with 'fs.s3.buffer.dir' property. Ideally it should delete and it does, but in some cases it does not delete those files, resulting in accumulation of a lot of .tmp files(in GBs). resulting in space issues.

Is there anyway that we can avoid the .tmp files creation?
Or somehow if we can identify why in some cases it does not delete those .tmp files and correct it?

Please suggest what can be the best solution in this case.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that you can do to help.

Enable automatic cleanup of the /tmp directory as a best practice, see the answer here: https://serverfault.com/questions/377348/when-does-tmp-get-cleared

Reference https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-10610 and enable automatic usage of multiple directories for tmp data to alleviate your large file issue

Create a JIRA against the Hadoop project to have tmp data stored in HDFS instead of on the local filesystem.

I am currently investigating this also and will attempt to update if I am able to find another mechanism to alleviate this issue.

Comment: Thanks Shawn for your valuable suggestions. My problem is not large files, but tmp files not getting deleted after job is killed(in very few cases). Using multiple dirs would not help in my case. But yes, Cron job for regular cleanup might help.